# Add kruskall-wallis and paiwise comparisons test outputs to dataframe

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis

I have several boxplots that I am running some statistics on through a for loop.

I want to be able to output the data into a dataframe. i.e. something like this (I've made up random numbers):

##### For the Kruskal-Wallis:

[image]

##### For the pairwise comparisons:

[image]

##### This is my code:

```
names <- c('B1','B2','B3')

for (name in names){
  mereLoc <- scaledDaily %>%
    filter(scaledDaily$loc == name)
  mereLoc$year <- as.numeric(mereLoc$year)
  median <- tapply(mereLoc$mAODscale, mereLoc$year, median, na.rm=T)
  print(name)
  print(median)

  krusk <- kruskal.test(mAODscale~year, data=mereLoc)
  print(krusk)

  pairs <- pairwise.wilcox.test(mereLoc$mAODscale, mereLoc$year, p.adjust.method='BH')
  print(pairs)
}
```

##### Test Data

here is some test data. its not my actual data, I've just fabricated some.

```
structure(list(loc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("B1", "B2", "B3"), class = "factor"), 
    mAODscale = c(0.561948848, 0.851883432, 0.293151829, 0.683807808, 
    0.864472706, 0.380303934, 0.324501709, 0.765022304, 0.900772901, 
    0.204731715, 0.877104175, 0.56367162, 0.206528162, 0.353350116, 
    0.219628257, 0.840723901, 0.716389918, 0.569798858, 0.707583441, 
    0.120064246, 0.275325307, 0.438391155, 0.308969668, 0.350156436, 
    0.886955315, 0.693416677, 0.710065022), year = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("1", 
    "2", "3"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I suspect the `broom` package will give you close to what you want with `tidy()`. If not, please clarify why it doesn’t.

Comment: @Limey. How would you add the results of that to a dataframe within the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
names <- c('B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7','B8',
           'SSSI1','SSSI2','SSSI3',
           "CM1", "CM2", "CM3", "CM4", "CM7", "CM8", "CM9", "CM11",
           "Crose 1", "Crose 2", "Crose 3")

stats <- list()
for (name in names){
  mereLoc <- scaledDaily %>%
    filter(scaledDaily$loc == name)
  mereLoc$year <- as.numeric(mereLoc$year)
  median <- aggregate(mereLoc$mAODscale, list(mereLoc$year), median, na.rm=T)
  
  krusk <- kruskal.test(mAODscale~year, data=mereLoc)
  krusk2 <- tidy(krusk)
  pairs <- pairwise.wilcox.test(mereLoc$mAODscale, mereLoc$year, p.adjust.method='BH')
  pairs2 <- tidy(pairs)

  stats[[name]] <- c("loc"=name, 
                     "Y1_median"=median$x[1], 
                     "Y2_median"=median$x[2],
                     "Y3_median"=median$x[3], 
                     "KWCHiSq"=krusk$statistic,
                     "df"=krusk$parameter,
                     "pvalue"=krusk$p.value, 
                     "Y1Y2"=pairs2[1,3], 
                     "Y1Y3"=pairs2[2,3],  
                     "Y2Y3"=pairs2[3,3])
}

stats <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y,all=TRUE), stats)
names(stats) <- c('loc','Y1_median','Y2_median','Y3_median',
                  'KW-ChiSq','df','pvalue','Y1-Y2','Y1-Y3','Y2-Y3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way.
If the data is in the long format then it is generally easier to process by `tidyverse` pipes. In the code below start by splitting by groups of location, run the tests, tidy as a data.frame and assemble the parts.
Reshape the results to wide format when needed.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(broom)
  library(tidyr)
})

bind_cols(
  scaledDaily %>%
    group_split(loc) %>%
    lapply(\(X) {
      loc <- first(X$loc)
      kruskal.test(mAODscale ~ year, data = X) %>% 
        tidy() %>%
        mutate(Location = loc) %>%
        relocate(Location)
    }) %>%
    do.call(rbind, args = .) %>%
    select(Location, statistic, p.value),
  scaledDaily %>%
    group_split(loc) %>%
    lapply(\(X) {
      X %>%
        group_by(year) %>%
        summarise(median = median(mAODscale)) %>%
        pivot_wider(
          names_from = year,
          names_glue = "Y{year}_median",
          values_from = median
        )
    }) %>%
    do.call(rbind, .) 
) %>% relocate(ends_with("median"), .after = Location)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   Location Y1_median Y2_median Y3_median statistic p.value
#>   <fct>        <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 B1           0.562     0.684     0.765     0.622   0.733
#> 2 B2           0.564     0.220     0.716     3.20    0.202
#> 3 B3           0.275     0.350     0.710     4.36    0.113


scaledDaily %>%
  group_split(loc) %>%
  lapply(\(X) {
    loc <- first(X$loc)
    pairwise.wilcox.test(X$mAODscale, X$year, p.adjust.method='BH') %>% 
      tidy() %>%
      mutate(Location = loc) %>%
      relocate(Location)
  }) %>%
  do.call(rbind, args = .) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = Location,
    names_from = starts_with("group"),
    names_glue = "Y{group1}_Y{group2}",
    values_from = p.value
  )
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   Location Y2_Y1 Y3_Y1 Y3_Y2
#>   <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 B1         1     1     1  
#> 2 B2         0.7   0.7   0.3
#> 3 B3         0.7   0.3   0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>